# Make title part of clickable area in UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a UIButton with an image and a long title. I've adjusted the button's titleEdgeInsets so that the text appears to the right of the button image.

```
    button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -BUTTONSIZE - button.titleLabel.frame.size.width - 15.0);
```

The problem is only the image is clickable for the button and not the long title to the right of it, I'd like to make that fire a click event as well. Is there a simple way of doing this or will I have to add some kind of overlying view?

Thanks

Comment: please share your code snippet, it will give more understanding.

Comment: My guess is that your button's title extend outside the button frame. In that case you must make your button larger.

Comment: @LGP was correct. I had to extend the frame of the button, as well as use setImage instead of setBackgroundImage on the button

Answer (score 0):

Get the touch point and check if It is within the range of the image:

```
- (IBAction)myAction:(UIButton *)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSSet *touches = [event touchesForView:sender];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:sender];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(touchPoint));
    if ( CGRectContainsPoint(imageFrame, touchPoint) ) {
        // Point lies inside the bounds.
    }
}
```